# Interference pattern double slit - exponential electric field

Tags: optics, interference, double-slit-experiment, complex-numbers

So I am trying to prove that the intensity received at a screen from a light point source through two slits is $I(x)=cos^2(\frac{\pi ax}{\lambda D})$. I know that the electric field at screen is $E(x)=e^{ikr}+e^{ik(r+\frac{ax}{D})}$, I am just struggling to move from this to the final form. I know that the intensity is proportional to the square of the electric field, so I tried squaring E up, but my maths is not working out, I keep getting combinations of sines and cosines that do not simplify to $cos^2$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably you just need some trig identities.  Things like $\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos(2x)$ or $\sin(2x) = 2\cos(x)\sin(x)$, etc.  Otherwise, it's not really possible to help without seeing the work that you've done.  That said, I suspect this problem will be considered a "homework-like" question, given that it's a check-my-math question and not about some conceptual problem in physics, so it's likely to be closed.

Comment: Why do you expect $I(x)=cos^2(\frac{\pi ax}{\lambda D})$?

Comment: Were taking to square or the squared norm of $E$? You said the former, but it should be the latter.

Comment: @my2cts It's the solution that was given to me. I just do not know how to get there.

Comment: @Sandejo what is the difference?

Comment: The square of a complex number is $(a+bi)^2=a^2+2abi-b^2$. The squared norm is $\lvert a+bi\rvert^2=a^2+b^2$.